# Inserir chaves estrangeiras

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Eu tenho duas tabelas e quando tento usar uma chave da 1º tabela na 2º o valor aparece NULL e deveria aparece os valores que aparecem no Aquario

```
CREATE TABLE Aquario(
    ANome varchar(64) PRIMARY KEY,
    Localizacao varchar(8),
    Capacidade integer(15));


CREATE TABLE Habitat(
    HNome varchar(100) PRIMARY KEY,
    Iluminamento integer(10),
    Salinidade integer(2),
    pH integer(2),
    Dureza integer(3),
    Oxigenacao integer(3),
    Temperatura integer(2),
    Percentagem_de_adequacao integer(2),
    ANome varchar(64),
    FOREIGN KEY (ANome) REFERENCES Aquario(ANome));

INSERT INTO Aquario(ANome,Localizacao,Capacidade) VALUES('Os Peixes azuis','Este',20);

INSERT INTO Habitat( HNome,Iluminamento , Salinidade,pH , Dureza, Oxigenacao, Temperatura,Percentagem_de_adequacao)  VALUES ('Os peixes',20,1,5,213,52,2,59);
```

Comment: A chave estrangeira serve pra você vincular um registro de uma tabela a outra, ou seja, ela não irá automaticamente buscar informações pra você em outra tabela.

Comment: Então como faço para obter os valores da 1º tabela para a 2º com FOREIGN KEY ?

Comment: Coloquei na resposta abaixo

Comment: Muito obrigado , ajudou muito

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A chave estrangeira serve pra você vincular um registro de uma tabela a outra, ou seja, ela não irá automaticamente buscar informações pra você em outra tabela.
E estrutura de tabela para o que você deseja ficaria assim:

```
CREATE TABLE Aquario(AId         integer(15) PRIMARY KEY,
                     ANome       varchar(64),
                     Localizacao varchar(8),
                     Capacidade  integer(15));


CREATE TABLE Habitat(HNome                    varchar(100) PRIMARY KEY,
                     Iluminamento             integer(10),
                     Salinidade               integer(2),
                     pH                       integer(2),
                     Dureza                   integer(3),
                     Oxigenacao               integer(3),
                     Temperatura              integer(2),
                     Percentagem_de_adequacao integer(2),
                     AId                      integer(integer),
                     FOREIGN KEY (AId) REFERENCES Aquario(AId));

INSERT INTO Aquario(AId,
                    ANome,
                    Localizacao,
                    Capacidade)
             VALUES(1,
                    'Os Peixes azuis',
                    'Este',
                    20);

INSERT INTO Habitat(HNome,
                    Iluminamento,
                    Salinidade,
                    pH,
                    Dureza,
                    Oxigenacao,
                    Temperatura,
                    Percentagem_de_adequacao,
                    AId)
             VALUES('Os peixes',
                    20,
                    1,
                    5,
                    213,
                    52,
                    2,
                    59,
                    1);
```

E para trazer os dados vinculados você utilizaria a seguinte `select`:

```
select h.hnome,
       a.nome
  from Habitat h
 inner join Aquario a on a.AId = h.AId;
```

Answer (score 1):

Outra pratica errada é vc usar nome como chave primaria. 
geralmente se usa numeros inteiros, no mysql é AUTO_INCREMENT.

Pense depois quando o usuário precisar de alterar o nome se ele for chave primaria e fazer referencia em outra tabela vai da problema.

```
CREATE TABLE animals (
     id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO animals (name) VALUES
    ('dog'),('cat'),('penguin'),
    ('lax'),('whale'),('ostrich');

SELECT * FROM animals;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html